# Removing Elements From a Linked List Recursively in C

Tags: c, list, recursion, hyperlink, destroy

I am currently studying for a test by doing practice problems the teacher posted for us to study off of and I am struggling with the deleting elements from a linked list recursively. I get an endless loop and I'm not quite sure why! Can someone please tip me into the right direction? I have made a method that deletes the elements without recursion (posted below) and tried to follow that was a guideline. However, I just cannot seem to get my recursion method to work.  Below is my code:

```
void destroyListRecursive(node *head)
{
    if ( head == NULL)
        return;

    destroyListRecursive(head->next);

    free(head);
}
```

Here is my none recursive function (which I looked at other articles to receive guidance on since I was having a few issues, please let me know if there is something wrong with it) :

```
void destroyList (struct node** head)
{
   struct node* current = *head;
   struct node* next;

   while (current != NULL) 
   {
       next = current->next;
       free(current);
       current = next;
   }

   *head = NULL;
}
```

Here is my list struct:

```
typedef struct node
{
    // data field
    int data;

    // the next node in the list
    struct node *next;
} node;
```

I'd really appreciate a nudge in the correct direction! :)

Comment: `if ( head->next == NULL)` ---> `if ( head == NULL)`. Otherwise you'll dereference a null pointer on last element.

Comment: @LPs I fixed that, but it still loops...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code dereference a NULL pointer on last element of your linked list with

```
if ( head->next == NULL)
    return;
```

When last element is passed recursively to the function its value will be in `head` parameter, so

```
if ( (NULL)->next == NULL)
    return;
```

That is [Undefined Behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)

Your recursive function must only check `head` value:

```
void destroyListRecursive(node *head)
{
    if ( head == NULL)
        return;

    destroyListRecursive(head->next);

    free(head);
}
```

Comment: I fixed it to that code, however, it still is an endless loop.

Comment: @starlight problem belongs to another piece of code you didn't post. Close this question as answered choosing one of the answers and post a new question with details.

Answer (score 0):

To my understandig, `head` should be freed in either case an the recursive call should be done only if the list has a tail. Furthermore, one could also cover the case in which the list is empty, which results in the following implementation.

```
void destroyListRecursive(node *head)
{
    if (head != NULL)
    {
        destroyListRecursive(head->next);
        free(head);
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried it that way and it made the endless loop worse, could it be something in another function?